# Is there a term that is divisible by $67$, in the sequence $10, 110, 1110, 11110, ...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divisibility

Consider the sequence
$10, 110, 1110, 11110, 111110, ...$

Here the $n$ the term $a_n=\sum \limits_{k=1}^n\left(10^k\right)$

Is there a term which is divisible by $67$ ?

How can we show that?

Comment: Should have said, you want a non-trivial solution to $10^n\equiv 10$ mod($67$).  Smallest solution is $n=34$ so $\frac {10^{34}-1}9-1$ is an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $68$ numbers: 
$$\underbrace{10, 110, 1110,..,11111110}_{68 \text{ terms of the sequence}}$$
Consider the residues which these numbers leave when divided by $67$. By the pigeonhole principle there are two numbers with the same residues, and thus their difference is divisible by $67$:
$$\underbrace{11111110}_{m \text{ digits}}-\underbrace{11111110}_{l \text{ digits}}=11..1100..00=\underbrace{11111110}_{s \text{ digits}} \cdot 10^k \cong 0 (\mod 67)$$
$$\gcd(10^k,67)=1 \Rightarrow 67| 11..110$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: He probably means "take 68 numbers", and should change his phrasing.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes thank you. I do not know much English

Comment: I've helped you with the English. Feel free to revert if you don't like it.

Comment: @ user21820: Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a curious way to figure it out without using Fermat's little theorem.

What is $\frac{1}{67}$ in decimal? Well we can perform long division. At each step you carry over a remainder, which is multiplied by $10$. Note that the remainder is never $0$, otherwise the decimal expansion ends, which is not possible since $67$ times the rightmost digit cannot produce a $0$. So the remainder must be from $1$ to $66$, and eventually the remainder will repeat itself since the decimal expansion goes on forever. Thus its digits would eventually repeat too!

Let us say that one of the remainders that repeats is $r$, and let $x$ be the string of digits that appear in the decimal expansion immediately after getting a remainder of $r$ and before getting the next remainder of $r$. Let $n$ be the number of digits in $x$. We can see that $r \times 1\underbrace{00\cdots0}_{\text{$n$ zeroes}}$ is a multiple of $67$ plus the next remainder of $r$. Therefore $r \times ( 1\underbrace{00\cdots0}_{\text{$n$ zeroes}} - 1) = r \times \underbrace{99\cdots9}_{\text{$n$ nines}} = r \times 9 \times \underbrace{11\cdots1}_{\text{$n$ ones}}$ is a multiple of $67$.

But $r \times 9$ is not divisible by $67$, so $\underbrace{11\cdots1}_{\text{$n$ ones}}$ must be divisible by $67$ since $67$ is prime (by Euclid's lemma).

Comment: Of course, Fermat's little theorem tells us that the number of digits in each repeating block must be a factor of $67 - 1 = 66$, but we did not need to know that in the above argument.

Comment: By the way, *Roman83*'s answer has the same underlying core as mine, but my method was in fact how I originally discovered the phenomenon in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

Using Fermat's little theorem, $$10^{\phi(m)}-1\equiv0\pmod m$$ for $(m,10)=1$

Now if $(m,9)=1\iff(m,3)=1,$ $$\dfrac{10^{\phi(m)}-1}{10-1}\equiv0\pmod m$$

Finally $\underbrace{11\cdots11}_{n \text{ digits}}=\dfrac{10^n-1}9$

Here, $m=67$

Alternatively, use Pigeonhole principle

Comment: How can we use Pigeonhole principle to show it?

Comment: @TharinduSathischandra, See the answer of  Roman83